# Finite extension of regular local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.  Let $A$ be a finitely generated regular $k$-algebra, and let $R$ be the localization of $A$ at a closed point $a\in\operatorname{Spec}A$.  Write $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R$ for the unique maximal ideal of $R$.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathfrak{m}$ be a regular system of parameters for $R$, that is, $x_1,\dots,x_n$ project to a basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$.  Then we have an injective algebra map
$$
k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}\to R
$$
My question is: is this map is always finite?

$ \ $

I think using a Noether normalization argument one can prove that there exists a system of parameters for which this map is finite.  To prove that, let us assume WLOG $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$ (localize $A$ by some element if not) and find elements $y_1,\dots,y_t$ which vanish at $a$ such that $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_t$ generate $A$.

Then by the proof of Noether normalization, we may take 
$$z_i=x_i-(\text{high degree polynomial in }y_i\text{'s})
$$
so that $A$ is finite over $k[z_1,\dots,z_n]$.  By construction, $z_1,\dots,z_n$ is a regular system of parameters for $R$.

$\ $

Even if the above is correct, I would like to know if the map is finite for any system of parameters.  Thanks for any comments/suggestions!

Comment: Your condition implies the map is unramified, but it is rarely finite. As an example, look at $R=k[x]_P$ where $P=(x-1)$. Then, take $y=x^2-1$, which is a regular parameter in $R$, but you can easily check that the map $k[y]_{(y)}\to R$ is not finite as follows. If it is, then it would be free and since $R/yR=k$, it has to be free of rank one and that means they are equal. But, they do not have the same fraction field, since $x$ is not in the fraction field $k(y)=k(x^2)$.

Comment: This is interesting.  Thanks for your response!  Is my Noether normalization argument even correct then?  I'm worried about it now....